# yum gives multilib version error

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, yum

I have two different arch of same package. `rpm -qa libvirt-client` gives output as-

`libvirt-client-3.9.0-14.el7_5.2.i686` and
`libvirt-client-1.2.17-13.el7.x86_64`. When I give `yum install libvirt-client` it gives me a error as-
`Error:  Multilib version problems found.`
`Protected multilib versions: libvirt-client-3.9.0-14.el7_5.6.x86_64 != libvirt-client-3.9.0-14.el7_5.2.i686`.

Is there a way to install both of these packages?.
And moreover `package-cleanup --dupes` does not return these packages.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/655141/centos-multilib-version-conflict

Comment: try to update the x86_64 lib together with the installation of the i686-lib:

yum install libvirt-client.x86_64 libvirt-client.i686

Comment: yeah this also works. Check my answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yum has as option `--setopt` which helps in ignoring the multilib problem. As -

`yum --setopt=protected_multilib=false install 'packageName'`